# How to get a secret-key reCaptcha for Contact Form 7

Tags: recaptcha, contact-form-7, secret-key

To integrate reCAPTCHA with Contact Form 7, you need to enter 2 codes Site key and The secret key.
[wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRUh1.png)
Google gave only one key Id, where to get the second code?
[secret-key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVUGg.png)

Comment: Are you integrating reCaptcha enterprise or reCaptcha V2/V3?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot provided it looks like you tried creating a key with reCaptcha enterprise (the payed version of reCaptcha).

reCaptcha enterprise typically does not authenticate the same way the free version of reCaptcha.  Instead of a site key and a secret key, you usually get a site key and an authentication file.

Unless you have a business reason to use reCaptcha enterprise, I suggest you use the free version of reCaptcha, there you will get both a site key and a secret key: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

You'll want to create a V3 reCaptcha if you want to use the secret score reCaptcha or V2 if you want to use the classic checkbox reCaptcha